# date not convering to europe/london timezone in php

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I'm working in a Cake PHP 2 web application where the default configuration is set to UTC. My model's `created` field I can see is saving in `UTC` (1 hour behind Europe/London, my current time).

When I retrieve my model in my view and output the contents of my `created` field it's the UTC time as saved in my db:

> 2022-08-12 15:31:05

But when trying to convert this to `Europe/London` using PHP datetime, it's not giving me the correct time of:

> 2022-08-12 16:31:05

The weird thing is that if I change my `Europe/London` in my `DateTimeZone` to `UTC` then it gives me:

> 2022-08-12 14:31:05

What am I missing to get the correct time:

```php
$created = new DateTime($automatedReport['ConsolidatedReport']['created']);
$created = $created->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$created = $created->format('D jS, H:i:s');
```

Comment: Set the correct timezone for the database.

Comment: The timezone is saving to the database correctly... `UTC`, if my model is pulling a `UTC` date then PHP should be able to convert this

Answer (score 1):

Create the date with UTC and then convert to London.

```
$created = new DateTime('2022-08-12 15:31:05', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$created = $created->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$created = $created->format('D jS, H:i:s');
```

gives

```
Fri 12th, 16:31:05
```